# How do you develop Java Servlets using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, plugins

I would like to program Java servlets using Eclipse and I plan on deploying them using Tomcat. I think I can build the projects using Ant which is bundled with Eclipse. I have the standard Eclipse IDE. What options do I have for doing Servlet development in Eclipse? What changes do I need to make to Eclipse? Do I need to install a plug-in?

Answer (score 104):

You need to install a plugin, There is a free one from the eclipse foundation called the [Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/). It has all the development functionality that you'll need.

You can get the [Java EE Edition of](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) eclipse with has it pre-installed.

To create and run your first servlet:

1. New... Project... Dynamic Web Project.
2. Right click the project... New Servlet.
3. Write some code in the `doGet()` method.
4. Find the servers view in the Java EE perspective, it's usually one of the tabs at the bottom.
5. Right click in there and select new Server.
6. Select Tomcat X.X and a wizard will point you to finding the installation.
7. Right click the server you just created and select *Add and Remove...* and add your created web project.
8. Right click your servlet and select Run > Run on Server...

That should do it for you. You can use ant to build here if that's what you'd like but eclipse will actually do the build and automatically deploy the changes to the server. With Tomcat you might have to restart it every now and again depending on the change.

Comment: Is the web tools platform supported in ADT as well? And I followed the link but cannot find the exact file. Can you help me with that?

Comment: isn't there some required configuration in the web.xml file?

Answer (score 7):

I use Eclipse Java EE edition

Create a "Dynamic Web Project"

Install a local server in the server view, for the version of Tomcat I'm using. Then debug, and run on that server for testing.

When I deploy I export the project to a war file.

Comment: Keeping things simple

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can use Jetty which is (now) part of the Eclipe Platform (the Help system is running Jetty). Besides Jetty is used by Android, Windows Mobile..

To get started check the [Eclipse Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Starting/Quick_Start_Guide)
or if you prefer a [Video](http://www.redmonk.com/cote/2009/04/16/jetty-at-eclipse-eclipsecon-2009/) 
And check out this related [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515654/what-is-a-lightweight-fast-java-servlet-container)!