# how to run java servelets in eclipse

Tags: servlets

can anyone please tell me how to run servelets on java eclipse from first stage and in my eclipse i am unable to find the dynamic web project option  how can i get that can anyone tell me with simple example like "hello world" program

Comment: the tag says 'applet' for a reason?

Comment: @Elijah Good question, re-tagged.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206924/how-do-you-develop-java-servlets-using-eclipse and it looks like you will need to install your own container such as Tomcat or Jetty.

Answer (score 1):

Check this http://keyboardsamurais.de/2004/01/15/tomcat_tutorial_helloworld_for_complete_fools_-_english/