# How do I get the Java servlet on my "eclipse juno" to work?

Tags: eclipse, servlets

**The problem**
Upon running the project through the "Run As" option on the server,
I keep getting the Http Status 404/Hello Servlet/

type           status report 
message       /HelloServlet/
description    the requested resource is not available

**What I have done.**

I have already gone through the questions such as these
[How do you develop Java Servlets using Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206924/how-do-you-develop-java-servlets-using-eclipse)

I have downloaded the apache tomcat windows installation from here
http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi

I have already set the targeted runtimes of my project to include Apache Tomcat 7.0

I have set the Java build path and used it to import the servlet-api jar.

Code
http://shrib.com/tVvVMzli
here is the code in case anybody wants to have a look.

Comment: By which URL are you trying to access it? Have you checked your logs that you don't have any startup errors?

Comment: URL?No i do not have any startup errors.